# How to uncompress a file originally compressed in a C# application?

Tags: c#, delphi, zip

I need to uncompress files that were originally compressed with a C# app, using the [SharpZipLib](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/help/api/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream.html) library. I'm using the Delphi zlib implementation, but I must be missing something, because when decompressing something that wasn't originally compressed by myself using zlib I get:

> Data Error

I'm using:

```delphi
procedure TfrmDownload.DescompactaArquivo(aNomeArquivo: string);
var
  _ArqCompact,
  _ArqDescompact: TFileStream;
  _Unzip: TDecompressionStream;

  function _GetNomeArquivoDesc: string;
  begin
    result := StringReplace(aNomeArquivo, '.zip', '', [rfIgnoreCase]);
  end;
begin
  if ((FileExists(aNomeArquivo)) and (Pos('.zip', aNomeArquivo) > 0)) then
  begin
    _ArqCompact := TFileStream.Create(aNomeArquivo, fmOpenRead);
    try
      _ArqDescompact := TFileStream.Create(_GetNomeArquivoDesc, fmCreate);
      try
        _Unzip := TDecompressionStream.Create(_ArqCompact, 31);
        try
          _ArqDescompact.CopyFrom(_Unzip, 0);
        finally
          FreeAndNil(_Unzip);
        end;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(_ArqDescompact);
      end;
      DeleteFile(aNomeArquivo);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(_ArqCompact);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Following AmigoJack's tip, I made an attempt to decompress using `System.Zip`:

```delphi
procedure TForm11.DecompactaZip(aNomeArquivo: string);
var
  _Zip: TZipFile;
begin
  _Zip := TZipFile.Create;
  try
    _Zip.Open(aNomeArquivo, zmRead);
    _Zip.ExtractAll(ExtractFilePath(aNomeArquivo));
    _Zip.Close;
  finally
    _Zip.Free;
  end;
end;
```

...but I get:

> stream read error

The file's content:

[image: Hex view of file]

Comment: You created a full [ZIP file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)), not [zlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) data alone. That's like creating a full JFIF file but wanting to interpret picture data off the first byte. Consider using [`TZipFile`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Extract).

Comment: Thank you AmigoJack, I tried to use TZipFile as depicted above, but I get "stream read error". The file is there on the destination folder, and it has the correct size, but it is useless....

Comment: I Might be missing something, but ZLib should be able to decompress Deflate compressed files.

Comment: Open your ZIP file in a [hex viewer](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) and verify that the first two bytes start with `#$50#$4b` (which are the ASCII letters `PK`), followed by the two bytes `#$03#$04`. Make sure one of the many unpacking programs (like [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)) are able to open/extract your file. In doubt make screenshots and edit your post. Include actual error messages instead of "did not work". No, zlib can decompress data, not files.

Comment: Thank´s again.  Yes, the first four bytes are 50 4B 03 04. Yes I can uncompress the file with 7zip and with windows11 native utility.  The error messages were both already included, which are: "Data Error" for the zLib Method and "stream read error" for the TZipFile Method. Finally, thank you for correcting my statement. Indeed, zlib deals with data, and not files.

Comment: Please don't put screen shots in your question. Copy and paste the hex data. Also provide more of a dump of the start of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot ends too early but looking at the "[local file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Local_file_header)"

- a filesize of `$ffffffff` and
- an extraction version of `$2d` = decimal 45 = PK version 4.5

indicate we're having a [Zip64 file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#ZIP64), which is yet another thing: not directly a ZIP file, not [zlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) data. Although it exists since 2001 by far not every implementation is able to properly read/support it.

[This addition](https://github.com/ccy/delphi-zip) looks like it adds Zip64 support, so try that. As a counter test set in your C# app the [`UseZip64`](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/help/api/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream.html#ICSharpCode_SharpZipLib_Zip_ZipOutputStream_UseZip64) property to `false` and create a new file - that should then be able to opened and extracted by Delphi's default implementation. As per formats you might want your Zip64 file to have a filename extension of `.zipx` and the normal ZIP file to have a filename extension of `.zip`.

If you come to the point where you're able to parse the ZIP/Zip64 file yourself, so you're able to spot each compressed file, and verify that the method is Deflate, you may use *zlib* on that compressed data stream to see if that single extracted file then has the same content as if *7-zip* has unpacked it.

Comment: Thank you. The Compression app, is not mine. But I´ll test the addition.